# Как вытащить из SVG, path cкругленного крестика?

Tags: html, css, svg

без фона (а задать его диву)

```css
/*div {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #002638;
}*/
```

```html
<div>
<svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M15 0H3C2.20435 0 1.44129 0.316071 0.87868 0.87868C0.316071 1.44129 0 2.20435 0 3V15C0 15.7956 0.316071 16.5587 0.87868 17.1213C1.44129 17.6839 2.20435 18 3 18H15C15.7956 18 16.5587 17.6839 17.1213 17.1213C17.6839 16.5587 18 15.7956 18 15V3C18 2.20435 17.6839 1.44129 17.1213 0.87868C16.5587 0.316071 15.7956 0 15 0ZM11.71 10.29C11.8037 10.383 11.8781 10.4936 11.9289 10.6154C11.9797 10.7373 12.0058 10.868 12.0058 11C12.0058 11.132 11.9797 11.2627 11.9289 11.3846C11.8781 11.5064 11.8037 11.617 11.71 11.71C11.617 11.8037 11.5064 11.8781 11.3846 11.9289C11.2627 11.9797 11.132 12.0058 11 12.0058C10.868 12.0058 10.7373 11.9797 10.6154 11.9289C10.4936 11.8781 10.383 11.8037 10.29 11.71L9 10.41L7.71 11.71C7.61704 11.8037 7.50644 11.8781 7.38458 11.9289C7.26272 11.9797 7.13201 12.0058 7 12.0058C6.86799 12.0058 6.73728 11.9797 6.61542 11.9289C6.49356 11.8781 6.38296 11.8037 6.29 11.71C6.19627 11.617 6.12188 11.5064 6.07111 11.3846C6.02034 11.2627 5.9942 11.132 5.9942 11C5.9942 10.868 6.02034 10.7373 6.07111 10.6154C6.12188 10.4936 6.19627 10.383 6.29 10.29L7.59 9L6.29 7.71C6.1017 7.5217 5.99591 7.2663 5.99591 7C5.99591 6.7337 6.1017 6.4783 6.29 6.29C6.4783 6.1017 6.7337 5.99591 7 5.99591C7.2663 5.99591 7.5217 6.1017 7.71 6.29L9 7.59L10.29 6.29C10.4783 6.1017 10.7337 5.99591 11 5.99591C11.2663 5.99591 11.5217 6.1017 11.71 6.29C11.8983 6.4783 12.0041 6.7337 12.0041 7C12.0041 7.2663 11.8983 7.5217 11.71 7.71L10.41 9L11.71 10.29Z" fill="#002638"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В примере склеены два path: Прямоугольник и крестик.

Место, где заканчивается один path и начинается второй path нужно искать по второй команде - `M(Moveto)`.

Разделение двух path произведено после второго символа `M` **...ZM11.71..."/>**

Крестику, чтобы его было видно присвоена  окраска - `fill="purple"`

**Крестик отдельно**

```html
<svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 

<path fill="purple" d="M11.71 10.29C11.8037 10.383 11.8781 10.4936 11.9289 10.6154C11.9797 10.7373 12.0058 10.868 12.0058 11C12.0058 11.132 11.9797 11.2627 11.9289 11.3846C11.8781 11.5064 11.8037 11.617 11.71 11.71C11.617 11.8037 11.5064 11.8781 11.3846 11.9289C11.2627 11.9797 11.132 12.0058 11 12.0058C10.868 12.0058 10.7373 11.9797 10.6154 11.9289C10.4936 11.8781 10.383 11.8037 10.29 11.71L9 10.41L7.71 11.71C7.61704 11.8037 7.50644 11.8781 7.38458 11.9289C7.26272 11.9797 7.13201 12.0058 7 12.0058C6.86799 12.0058 6.73728 11.9797 6.61542 11.9289C6.49356 11.8781 6.38296 11.8037 6.29 11.71C6.19627 11.617 6.12188 11.5064 6.07111 11.3846C6.02034 11.2627 5.9942 11.132 5.9942 11C5.9942 10.868 6.02034 10.7373 6.07111 10.6154C6.12188 10.4936 6.19627 10.383 6.29 10.29L7.59 9L6.29 7.71C6.1017 7.5217 5.99591 7.2663 5.99591 7C5.99591 6.7337 6.1017 6.4783 6.29 6.29C6.4783 6.1017 6.7337 5.99591 7 5.99591C7.2663 5.99591 7.5217 6.1017 7.71 6.29L9 7.59L10.29 6.29C10.4783 6.1017 10.7337 5.99591 11 5.99591C11.2663 5.99591 11.5217 6.1017 11.71 6.29C11.8983 6.4783 12.0041 6.7337 12.0041 7C12.0041 7.2663 11.8983 7.5217 11.71 7.71L10.41 9L11.71 10.29Z"/>

</path>
```

**Квадрат отдельно:**

```html
<svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path fill="purple" d="M15 0H3C2.20435 0 1.44129 0.316071 0.87868 0.87868C0.316071 1.44129 0 2.20435 0 3V15C0 15.7956 0.316071 16.5587 0.87868 17.1213C1.44129 17.6839 2.20435 18 3 18H15C15.7956 18 16.5587 17.6839 17.1213 17.1213C17.6839 16.5587 18 15.7956 18 15V3C18 2.20435 17.6839 1.44129 17.1213 0.87868C16.5587 0.316071 15.7956 0 15 0Z"/> 
 </svg>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: @elka Рад был помочь

Comment: @Leonid заслужил конечно, просто читаю пока код, отвлекают ещё домашние

Answer (score 1):

Можно попытаться автоматизировать процесс. Тут не учитывается если viewBox будет иметь отрицательные значения для начальной точки, но это тоже можно добавить.

```js
const paths = document.querySelector('svg path').getAttribute('d').split(/[mM]/).slice(1).map(path => 'M' + path);
const [x,y,w,h] = document.querySelector('svg').getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ').map(unit => +unit);

paths.forEach(path => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = w + 40;
    canvas.height = h + 40;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    canvas.setAttribute('data-path', path);
    
    ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w + 40,h + 40);
    ctx.translate(20,20);
    ctx.fill(new Path2D(path));
    
    canvas.addEventListener('click', showPath);
    
    document.body.append(canvas);
})

function showPath(event){
    const path = event.target.dataset.path;
  console.clear();
    console.log(path);
}
```

```css
canvas {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
<path d="m15 0H3C2.20435 0 1.44129 0.316071 0.87868 0.87868C0.316071 1.44129 0 2.20435 0 3V15C0 15.7956 0.316071 16.5587 0.87868 17.1213C1.44129 17.6839 2.20435 18 3 18H15C15.7956 18 16.5587 17.6839 17.1213 17.1213C17.6839 16.5587 18 15.7956 18 15V3C18 2.20435 17.6839 1.44129 17.1213 0.87868C16.5587 0.316071 15.7956 0 15 0ZM11.71 10.29C11.8037 10.383 11.8781 10.4936 11.9289 10.6154C11.9797 10.7373 12.0058 10.868 12.0058 11C12.0058 11.132 11.9797 11.2627 11.9289 11.3846C11.8781 11.5064 11.8037 11.617 11.71 11.71C11.617 11.8037 11.5064 11.8781 11.3846 11.9289C11.2627 11.9797 11.132 12.0058 11 12.0058C10.868 12.0058 10.7373 11.9797 10.6154 11.9289C10.4936 11.8781 10.383 11.8037 10.29 11.71L9 10.41L7.71 11.71C7.61704 11.8037 7.50644 11.8781 7.38458 11.9289C7.26272 11.9797 7.13201 12.0058 7 12.0058C6.86799 12.0058 6.73728 11.9797 6.61542 11.9289C6.49356 11.8781 6.38296 11.8037 6.29 11.71C6.19627 11.617 6.12188 11.5064 6.07111 11.3846C6.02034 11.2627 5.9942 11.132 5.9942 11C5.9942 10.868 6.02034 10.7373 6.07111 10.6154C6.12188 10.4936 6.19627 10.383 6.29 10.29L7.59 9L6.29 7.71C6.1017 7.5217 5.99591 7.2663 5.99591 7C5.99591 6.7337 6.1017 6.4783 6.29 6.29C6.4783 6.1017 6.7337 5.99591 7 5.99591C7.2663 5.99591 7.5217 6.1017 7.71 6.29L9 7.59L10.29 6.29C10.4783 6.1017 10.7337 5.99591 11 5.99591C11.2663 5.99591 11.5217 6.1017 11.71 6.29C11.8983 6.4783 12.0041 6.7337 12.0041 7C12.0041 7.2663 11.8983 7.5217 11.71 7.71L10.41 9L11.71 10.29Z" fill="#002638"/>
</svg>
<h3>
Кликните на элемент для получения его пути
</h3>
```

P.S. Код выше не учитывает, что могут попасться инструкции `m` в середине (они неправильно будут заменены на `M`). Поэтому предлагаю следующие изменения для массива путей:

```
const paths = document.querySelector('svg path').getAttribute('d').split('').reduce((acc,char) => {
    if(/[Mm]/.test(char)){
        acc.push(char);
    } else {
        acc[acc.length - 1] += char;
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: `.getAttribute('d').split(/[mM]/).slice(1).map(path => 'M' + path)` - единственное полезное здесь. Правда вот не могу найти `M` и `m` одно и то же вначале, а вот в середине может разные? `m` может быть по относительному смещению?

Comment: Зачёт!!!  Здесь => `map(path => 'M' + path` ещё наверное нужно учесть и маленькую `m` - когда относительное начало бывает Надо же, одновременно думали.. в середине разные значения `m` `M`

Comment: Да, но тогда надо код менять, надо помнить какую букву удалил, уже не так элегантно в одну строчку будет))

Comment: можно из относительных координат перевести в абсолютные и разделять по `M` [Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv)

Comment: [Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv)

Comment: Можно, но нюансов тут еще много, например, я не проверяю замкнут ли контур. Это же может быть просто штрих, например. Или одна фигура складывается из внешнего и внутреннего контура (evenodd). Скажем, достаточно хорошо))) Еще внешний код для этого подключать))) Мне же нужны только два числа после М, там все гораздо проще. А чтобы все превести в абсолютную, надо учитывать отдельные команды, сколько за ними координат должно быть для каждой. И так далее... Да и здесь проще переписать на аккумуляторы путей, чтобы на команду M/m новый путь начинался и все.

Comment: Все, мегаисправил((

Comment: вроде понял, если M то разделяет, иначе `m` всё равно разделяет path А вот если несколько путей, больше двух и комбинации соседних путей разные Mm;  mM; MM; mm будет работать?

Comment: Я разбиваю атрибут `d` на символы (`char`). Перебираю массив символов методом reduce (создаю аккумулятор - пустой массив `acc`). Если текущий символ - M или m, то помещаю его в массив `acc` (создаю новый строчный элемент массива). Любой другой символ добавляется к последнему элементу в массиве (к строке, начинающейся с символа M или m). Все будет работать в любых сочетаниях и любом количестве отдельных кривых (путей).

Comment: отлично, надо только внести добавки из PS в основной код и попробовать, на трех, четырех путях **одновременно**, если сработает и будет выводить пути, то это очень круто!!

Comment: Однако, тупанул я)) Букву то сохранил, а вот смысл утерялся же. В отдельном пути маленькая буква m ничего не значит, информация же утеряна... Надо доработать.

Comment: Точно, в худшем случае мне по цепочке придется до первых координат первого пути дойти чтобы получить абсолютное значение начала пути. Так что надо полностью переводить весь путь в абсолютный. А так мы не договаривались.

Comment: Ну так я это с самого начала предлагал...

Comment: Нет, не проблема пройтись по паре чисел, держа в уме текущую команду. И если это версия относительная, то добавлять к предыдущим координатам. Но это явно не для этого вопроса. Предлагаю закинуть такой вопрос)))

Comment: так сделай вопрос-ответ сам, ты же больше погрузился в тему, плюс подбери подходящие path с чередованием M,m